# C# How To Display Decimal Value with Suffix?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, type-conversion, double, decimal

I know this is basic but I can't still find the correct answer online.

I'm trying to display a decimal value like so:

> 51.00M

However I'm struggling converting my double value to decimal and also outputting the suffix (M) as well.

**Here's my code:**

```
Payment.PaymentTotal = 51.0;
decimal saleamount = System.Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", Payment.PaymentTotal));
System.Console.WriteLine("Converted Amount: " + (decimal)saleamount);
```

**My output is:**

> 51.00

But I'm trying to get the suffix which should be "51.00M" so I can add that value to an object that needs a decimal with suffix.

Comment: M stands for money. I'm passing these values through Paypal API and they are strict with the datatypes.

Comment: Where is the `M` in your last line of code (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xkyvob)? Why do you cast `saleamount` to `decimal` when it is already `decimal`?

Comment: `decimal saleamount = System.Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.00}", Payment.PaymentTotal));` why not use `decimal saleamount = System.Convert.ToDecimal(Payment.PaymentTotal);`?

Comment: Thanks @Mjwills I tried converting using ToDecimal but it's still outputting as 51, not 51.00M. I'm starting to think it's not possible to output decimal suffixes.

Comment: @mjwills - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/dotnet

Comment: You are misreading the documentation. The M is not in the string. M, in C# code, means `decimal`. You don't need to worry about it. If your variable is of type `decimal` you are fine. You are trying to solve a non-existent problem.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills for the clarification. I'll try again.